# Eigenvalues of sum of a tridiagonal matrix and another matrix whose square is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

$A$ is a tridiagonal matrix of the form $$\left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc}d_1&a&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\a&d_2&a&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\0&a&d_3&a&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\0&0&a&d_4&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&d_{n-3}&a&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&a&d_{n-2}&a&0\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&a&d_{n-1}&a\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&a&d_{n}
\end{array}\right)$$

and $B$ is another symmetric matrix of the form $$\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc}0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&a\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&a&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&a&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
a&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right)\cdot$$

Non-zero entries of $B$ are at the following places:

$B(1,n)=B(n,1)=a,\\B(4,n-1)=B(n-1,4)=a,\\B(5,n-4)=B(n-4,5)=a,\\B(8,n-5)=B(n-5,8)=a,\\B(9,n-8)=B(n-8,9)=a,\\\cdots$

Note that $B^2$ is the diagonal matrix $\mbox{diag}(a^2,0,0,a^2,a^2,0,0,a^2,a^2,\ldots,a^2)$.

What would be an efficient way to find the eigenvalues of $A+B$?

Comment: Could you explain more the matrix B? I don't understand its form. Which entries are $a$?

Comment: Even finding the eigenvalues of $A$ is not simple, although the structure is know. (This is known as tight binding with diagonal impurities in physics).

Comment: For $A+B$, note that $A$ can be diagonalized. $B$ seems to be a rank two matrix. Then you can find an equation for the eigenvalues of $A+B$ (which in general you won't be able to solve). What properties of the spectrum are you interested in? (Maybe some answers to this question can be given)

Comment: @RedPhoenix Sorry! The matrix $B$ is not really well explained. I edit the question now.

Comment: @lcv $B$ is not a rank two matrix indeed. Please see the edited question. You have correctly pointed out that finding the eigenvalues of $A$ is not even easy. In my case, all the diagonal entries are not distinct, there is a pattern and this makes it a bit easier.

Comment: Yes the form of $B$ was definitely not clear. What is the rank of $B$? The method i was alluding to kind of works for higher rank but gets increasingly complicated.

Comment: @lcv Rank of $B$ is $\frac{n+1}{2}$ and $n\equiv 1(\mod 4)$ here.

Comment: I don't think that the impurity method would work then, but who knows. You can look at papers by P W Anderson (on what will be described as Anderson localization), but in general it seems a very hard problem. Can $A$ be diagonalized easily? You can check if there is some structure in $[A,B]$ and higher commutators, but I doubt..